# yt-dlp 'rate-limit' not throttiling speed in Python script

Tags: python, bandwidth-throttling, ytdl

I have implemented yt-dlp as part of my Python script, it works well, but I am unable to get the rate-limit feature to work.
If you run the same command from the CLI the rate is limited correctly, is anyone able to tell me the correct syntax?

I have tried several combinations such as rate-limit, limit-rate 0.5m, 500k, 500KiB, 500, and none seem to work

```
        ydl_opts = {
        'limit-rate': '500k',

    }

    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([link])
```

I am using the docs here; https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp
But am confused as the CLI command works but not the embedded script version,

I also tried replacing - with _ but still to no effect, do you have any ideas?
Other options in the ydl_opts work without issue

Hopefully we can resolve the correct syntax rather than having to implement Trickle or throttling the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/master/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py) you'll find that the option you're looking for is called `ratelimit`. Its value should be a float:

```
ydl_opts = {
        'ratelimit': 500000
    }

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(params=ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([link])
```

Answer (score 2):

crawfr's answer is correct. but instead of randomly searching through the source code, all the options are documented by doscstrings. `ratelimit` can be found in the [docstring of `FileDownloader` class](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/d8cf8d97a8dbc9602556de474af133b5ab0e0a29/yt_dlp/downloader/common.py#L26)

Since it is in the docstring, you can also use the python `help` to retrieve this if you don't want to manually go through the source files

```
>>> from yt_dlp import FileDownloader
>>> help(FileDownloader)
Help on class FileDownloader in module yt_dlp.downloader.common:

class FileDownloader(builtins.object)
 |  FileDownloader(ydl, params)
 |
 |  File Downloader class.
...
 |  ratelimit:          Download speed limit, in bytes/sec.
...
```

PS: Writing as answer since not enough reputation to comment